# Simplifying If-conditions

Tags: java, if-statement, simplify

**Is there a way to simplify:**

```
if(a == b || a == o || a == j || a ==....)
{
    ...
}
```

I thought I could do something like

```
if( a == (b || o || j || ...))
{
     ...
}
```

But that turned out to be incorrect syntax

Comment: Nothing as simple as that.  You could put your values in the list and then use `contains()`.

Comment: If b, o, j and such are constants one could make a Set (java 9: `Set.of(b, o, j).contains(a)`. `Arrays.asList(b, o, j).contains(a)` If they are variables, the logic smells.

Comment: You can't simplify `if` like that unfortunately. If a `switch` statement makes sense in your case, you can have multiple `case`s together. Otherwise the collection-based suggestions probably make the most sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a method to take the value of `a` and a *varargs* of the other elements, then you can stream over the elements and check if any is equal to the value of `a`.

an example:

```
public boolean anyMatch(int a, int... values){
      return Arrays.stream(values).anyMatch(e -> e == a);
}
```

then you can call it like so:

```
if(anyMatch(a, o, j, b)){ ... };
```

Comment: The way to use java 8 advantages :)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose your variables are integers.

```
List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(b, o, j);
if (values.contains(a)){
...
}
```